# MvvmCross Xamarin.Forms iOS application never launches on iPhone Simulator and simulator remains black

Tags: iphone, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am developing Xamarin.Forms Application using MVVMCross. The application works perfectly in Android but in iOS, when I deploy the app, iPhone Simulator is black and it seems completely dead. And in Visual Studio 2019, its showing that App is Launching in iPhone Xs 12.0 and it remains this forever

Comment: Kindly see Application Output and console for more details. You will get more idea for what's happening in the App. I suspect there would some exception that would be thrown.

Comment: Output or stacktrace for the same would help!

Comment: Thankyou @Nikhil and Ali.

 when I try debugging the app, the console windows just shows this "Launching App on iPhone 6s Plus iOS 12.2..." and nothing else. But only sometimes it says that iOS App doesn't has a Signing Certificate. But I was more concerened that why the iPhone Simulator is a dead black window? Shouldn't it atleast work like the Android Emulator works?

Comment: Could be anything, post some code.

Comment: Post your `AppDelegate`, `Setup` (if you have any), `App` and `AppStart` (if you have any)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who tried to help. But I have found the answer.

There were no error logs or exceptions thrown, whenever I tried to deploy or debug the code in Simulator, it just kept showing that App is Launching in the iPhone XS ...
The problem was that I had not selected "Remote Simulator to Windows" (Options->Xamarin->iOS Settings-> Simulator). Checking this option, resolved the issue.